# Add text to active TextField in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, keyboard, textfield

I'm building a calculator/graphing app with Swift and SwiftUI and I have a bunch of TextFields in a list, all of them with a keyboard type of .decimalpad. I want to have a button that adds a custom string (scientific notation i.e. "e+1") to the active TextField, so the final result would be "15.54e+1" for example. I'm using an API called KeyboardToolbar to add buttons over the keyboard. Is there a way to do what I want in SwiftUI?

[image: TextFields with decimalpad image]